# After a hotfix, when I launch the Kentico site, I see offline page

Tags: upgrade, kentico

After Upgrade kentico to 10, and fix errors in code. I launch the kentico site, and see offline page:

[image: screenshot]

Who can know why this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please delete the App_Offline.htm file in the /CMS folder. That file is created if there were errors during upgrade or hotfix.

you must missed the warning message during upgrade that tells you the site will be put into offline mode with that file when all the errors showed up.